# Limit of expectations on increasing sigma algebra converge to expectation on limit sigma algebra

Tags: probability-theory, conditional-expectation, martingales

Let $\mathcal{F}_t=\sigma\{B_s:s\le t\}$ be the Brownian filtration and $t_n\nearrow T>0$ and let $Y\in\mathcal{F}_T$. I am having trouble understanding why the martingale convergence theorem implies that $Y_n:=E(Y|\mathcal{F}_{t_n})$ converges to $E(Y|\mathcal{F}_T)$. I understand that there is a random variable $Y_{\infty}$ such that $Y_n\to Y_{\infty}$ but why does this limit has the form $Y_{\infty}=E(Y|\mathcal{F}_T)$?

Also, I am not sure why $Y_n$ is a martingale. I have $E(Y_{n+1}|\sigma(Y_1,\ldots,Y_n))=E(E(Y|\mathcal{F}_{t_{n+1}})|\sigma(Y_1,\ldots,Y_n))$ so it seems that I need to show $\sigma(Y_1,\ldots,Y_n)=\mathcal{F}_{t_n}$ to conclude, but how is this done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, $\{Y_n\}$ here is a martingale w.r.t. $\{\mathcal{F}_n\equiv \mathcal{F}_{t_n}\}$ because $\mathcal{F}_n\subset \mathcal{F}_{n+1}$ and
$$
\mathsf{E}[Y_{n+1}\mid\mathcal{F}_n]=\mathsf{E}[\mathsf{E}[Y\mid \mathcal{F}_{n+1}]\mid\mathcal{F}_n]=\mathsf{E}[Y\mid \mathcal{F}_n]=Y_n.
$$
Second, if $Y_n$ converges in $L^1$ to some random variable $Y_{\infty}$, the latter equals $\mathsf{E}[Y\mid \mathcal{F}_T]$ a.s. because for each $n\ge 1$, $Y_n=\mathsf{E}[Y_{\infty}\mid \mathcal{F}_n]$. (See Lemma 4.6.6 and Theorem 4.6.8 on page 247 [here](https://services.math.duke.edu/%7Ertd/PTE/PTE5_011119.pdf) for details.)

Comment: Thanks. Everything is clear except for one detail. With the definition of Durrett It seems $\mathcal{F}_{\infty}:=\sigma(\cup_{n\ge 1}\mathcal{F}_{t_n})=\sigma\{B_s:s<T\}$. However, $\mathcal{F}_T=\sigma\{B_s:s\le T\}$ witht the "$\le$" sign instead of "$<$".

Comment: @edamondo https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/973968/why-is-the-canonical-filtration-of-a-brownian-motion-left-continuous

Comment: Basically, $\mathcal{F}_{\infty}=\mathcal{F}_T$ if $(B_t)$ is continuous (everywhere).

Comment: Oh, this is actually just because of the definition of the right continuity of the Brownian filtration which means $\sigma(\cup_{s<t}\mathcal{F}_s)=\mathcal{F}_t$ right?

Comment: @edamondo Hmm. Although it is true that $\mathcal{F}_{t-}=\mathcal{F}_t$ (by the continuity of sample paths of $B$), $\mathcal{F}_t\subset \mathcal{F}_{t+}$. The augmented natural filtration is right-continuous.

Comment: But isn't the sample path only almost surely continuous? So in the link you provide doesn't "augment the filtration" mean to make it left continuous?

Comment: It depends. Where does your questions come from? Are there any assumptions about continuity?